# Master Page setting

Tags: html, css

I have three div's (name as Header, Center and Footer respectively ) on master page,
when ever the  content in center div is increasing or decreasing, or you can say that the height of center div is changed due to the content size in it. then footer div position is also changed, how can i fix height of both div's at one position. can any body guide me about it.

thanks

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: @Umair your question is not clear... exactly what you want? provide real time problem/code/fiddle etc.

Comment: If the content in `Center` div increases, but `Footer` doesn't move, what should happen? Otherwise `Center` content will overlap `Footer` content.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the fix height of divs and set overflow property of div is true.
This solve your content issue.